# I'm facing a problem with redirecting in class-based success_url

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

I'm working with Django 2.2 and I'm facing a problem with redirecting in class-based success URL.

```
enter code here - view.py

class LetterFormView(CreateView):
   template_name = 'post.html'
   model = Letter
   form_class = LetterForm


def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse ('mainapp:user-profile')
```

and the url.py

```
enter code here- urls.py

path('profile/<username>/', views.UserProfilePage.as_view(), name='user-profile'),
```

```
class Letter(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    Text = models.TextField()
```

This is how my model looks like

Now I'm not sure how to pass the username argument in here.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass url parameters in reverse function using kwargs.

```
reverse ('mainapp:user-profile', kwargs={'username':self.object.username})
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your support. but it gives an error 'Letter' object has no attribute 'username'. Do you know how to fix it? I have added the model in the question too, in case if you need to see it.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing a level of indentation on the `get_success_url` method; it needs to fall within `class LetterFormView`:

```
class LetterFormView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'post.html'
    model = Letter
    form_class = LetterForm


    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse ('mainapp:user-profile')
```

Also, be sure to indent with four spaces to adhere to PEP-8; you seem to be indenting with three spaces within the class.

Answer (score 0):

you can try on view code

```
class LetterFormView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'post.html'
    model = Letter
    form_class = LetterForm

    def get_success_url(self):
       return reverse('mainapp:user-profile', kwargs={'username': self.object.username')})
```

`self.object.username` please use how to condition with model structure on your project

and than on urls code don't forget to initilize data type on **`username`** argument

```
path('profile/<str:username>/', views.UserProfilePage.as_view(), name='user-profile'),
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your support. but it gives an error 'Letter' object has no attribute 'username'. Do you know how to fix it? I have added the model in the question too, in case if you need to see it.

Comment: try this **self.object.author** or **self.object.author.username**